# Does AIR for iOS use captive runtime?

Tags: ios, air, adobe

This [article from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html) states that AIR for iOS apps include the captive runtive:

> Note that the captive runtime is the only option that is available
>   when using AIR to target iOS. Since iOS does not support a shared
>   runtime model, the captive model remains the only option on this
>   platform.

But this [second article from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html) confuses the issue for me:

> When you build your application for iOS, there is no interpreted code
>   and no runtime in your final binary. Your application is truly a
>   native iOS app.

Is the second article wrong/out of date? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is correct. Basically:

1. You cannot have an Adobe AIR app installed and access the SDK within that app, like you can with Android. This means the SDK **must** be in the app itself, i.e. Captive Runtime
2. Apple doesn't allow interpreted code in the iTunes Store. Your app must run Objective-C. So you can't use the Android-version of captive runtime where your app runs AS3 through the runtime that is installed on your app (which can be seen as a Flash Player, for the most part).

For iOS, Adobe AIR actually cross-compiles your code and the necessary AIR runtime components to Objective-C, which is what that second quote alludes to. When you do a release build to iOS, your app is actually Objective-C, not Actionscript or Flex. This is why, prior to AIR 14 & 15 where they rewrote the compiler, iOS compilation took so long to compile (5-20 mins depending on hardware). Your app is 100% Objective-C after compilation, including the runtime itself so that Apple will accept the app in the app store.